# Kill processes inside docker container after daemon restart

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm using docker 1.1.0 with default driver on ubuntu 14.04.

Restarting docker daemon does not affect running processes inside container: they are still running, but `docker ps` does not show any running containers. All these processes now have `/sbin/init` as parent process (instead of `/usr/bin/docker -d`).

Is it possible to automatically kill all these processes whenever its parent process (`docker -d`) is killed?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope this is not about ubuntu actually, this is about docker.

Comment: Seems strange to me since Docker daemon should kill every running process under him when he go down. Did you specify particular option in your run command ?

Comment: As far as I can see this is a bug related to Ubuntu's `upstart`. You might want to checkout Docker on github e.g. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6673 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6647.